# Watson Data API - Creating a project fails

Tags: git, rest, watson-studio

Utilizing the `Watson Studio GUI`, I have no problems creating a `Studio` project and integrating it with a `git` repo. I need to `script` this process. When using the `Watson Data API (2.23.1)`, I can indeed create a project using the `.../transactional/v2/projects` `REST` call, but that call doesn't appear to have any `git` related info in its `payload`.

After creating the project (not yet integrated with `git`), I then try issuing this `REST` call:
`.../v2/asset_files/git_transactions/remote` passing the newly created project.

Its payload contains `git` info, so I assume it's the one to use to integrate the project with `GIT`:

```
{"repo_url": "https://github.ibm.com/orgn/xxxx.git","access_token":{"git_host":"GitHub Enterprise","token_value":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx" }}
```

But this call always fails with:

> `{"code":400,"error":"Bad Request","reason":"Invalid request body, access_token format is not valid","message":"The server cannot or will not process the request due to an apparent client error (e.g. malformed request syntax)."}`

The message mentions the `access_token` format being invalid, but I'm following the api documentation wrt format.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the Swagger doc for Watson Studio projects at: https://api.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/v2/projects/docs/swagger/#/

If so, you will see that you can include the GH integration in your project creation step.

You can use the [GetProject](https://api.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/v2/projects/docs/swagger/#/Projects/getProject) API to grab the JSON from your working project with the GH integration already working to confirm the schema required.

Comment: Unfortunately, while the Swagger doc suggests it would support "github" as element in the Post, I receive an "Extraneous properties: github" message when I include it.

Comment: Note: I have just confirmed with a watson studio developer that the REST API currently doesn't support project GIT integration.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, you are correct that the /transactional/v2/projects api endpoint does not support including GitHub integration whereas the /v2/projects api endpoint does but it is not the recommended one to use programmatically.

That said, there is a [update API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/watson-data-api#update-project) which will allow you to add your GitHub integration to your newly created project which you created via the transactional/v2/projects api assuming that you have already added your GitHub access token to your Watson Studio Setting as per [Enable access to GitHub from your account](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/github-integration.html?linkInPage=true)

You can simply pass the body:

```
{
"github": {
        "repository": "https://github.ibm.com/orgn/xxxx.git"
         }
}
```

And your project will be updated accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

I've tried to update project which created via the transaction/v2/projects api and already added GitHub access token.

After that I can see that it is applied it (/v2/projects/{projects id}), but it is not applied Integrations section in Projects setting page.
I think it is not being update to backend pod.

Comment: This does not looks like an answer at all but just a small footsteps. Please consider reading this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer